# Ошибка сборки: Cannot find -lGL

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5

При попытке сборки проекта Qt Widgets выдает вот такую ошибку:

> g++ -Wl,-rpath,/home/keyreal/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib -o untitled3 main.o        mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.o   -L/home/keyreal/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Widgets -L/usr/lib64 -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread
>   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [untitled3] Ошибка 1
>   22:41:13: Процесс «/usr/bin/make» завершился с кодом 2.
>   Ошибка при сборке/установке проекта untitled3 (комплект: Desktop Qt 5.7.0 GCC 64bit)`

Ошибку выдает только если создается проект Qt Widgets, с консольным приложением вроде всё работает. Проект создается пустой абсолютно, т.е. туда ничего не внесено и никаких дополнительных классов не используется

ОС - Ubuntu 14.04 с XFCE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Установите пакет `libgl1-mesa-dev`.

**Добавлено**

Разумеется, нет возможности гарантировать, что на неких специфичных убунтах с нестандартным набором установленных пакетов, обозначенный пакет не затребует что-либо удалить. Речь о стандартной поставке Ubuntu с Gnome, начиная с 14.04 и по 16.04 включительно. Подозреваю, что и для более ранних версий, а также для версий с XFCE ситуация не изменится (самолично не проверял, не пользуюсь этим DE).

Предоставляемые пакетом файлы:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gl.pc
/usr/share
/usr/share/bug
/usr/share/bug/libgl1-mesa-dev
/usr/share/bug/libgl1-mesa-dev/control
/usr/share/bug/libgl1-mesa-dev/script
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libgl1-mesa-dev
/usr/share/doc/libgl1-mesa-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libgl1-mesa-dev/copyright
```

Как видно, пакет содержит искомую библиотеку: `libGL.so`

При установке на систему Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome ничего не запрашивает снести.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не могли бы вы более подробно описать решение. На сколько я помню, в процессе установки mesa попросить удалить огромное количество пакетов x11. Было бы очень здорово увидеть несколько вариантов решения, если вы пробовали что–либо кроме приведенного в ответе метода.

Comment: Если просто поставить mesa, как в ответе, согласившись снести X11, Ubuntu сломается. Понятно, что графический режим отвалится, но может и сломаться совсем. И восстанавливать ой как долго. Прям так долго, что проще ОС по новой поставить.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, это не так, это dev-пакет, который не потребует что-либо удалять. Во всяком случае с 14 по 16 убунты (после установки системы) я пользуюсь этим решением.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, Вы перепутали, видимо, с другим пакетом. Прямо сейчас на убунту 16.04 я удалил этот пакет и поставил заново. Ничего иного, кроме него, не было удалено или установлено.

Comment: К сожалению, нет под рукой виртуальной машины проверить. В любом случае, если, как вы говорите, это «dev пакет», простой установкой не отделаться, необходимо указать Qt, где находится библиотека.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, и указывать ничего не надо после установки. Qt всё автоматом цепляет.

Comment: Спасибо большое, заработало

Comment: @alexis031182 Видимо, все стало проще. Здорово!

Comment: @КириллАпкаримов, пожалуйста. Сам я тоже постоянно забываю название пакета, а здесь теперь как в закладках :)

Comment: Была такая же ошибка на Linux Mint (тоже с XFCE), решил установкой `libgl1-mesa-dev`: sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev