# Не собирается проект Qt 5.14.1 GCC 64bit

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5

Не собирается проект, я так понимаю из за отсутствия какой-то библиотеки

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
```

Вот полный вывод:

```
14:56:34: Выполняются этапы для проекта calendarwidget...
14:56:34: Запускается: «/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/bin/qmake» /home/nikita/Projects/calendarwidget/calendarwidget.pro -spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=qml_debug
Info: creating stash file /home/nikita/Projects/build-calendarwidget-Desktop_Qt_5_14_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/.qmake.stash
14:56:34: Процесс «/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/bin/qmake» завершился успешно.
14:56:34: Запускается: «/usr/bin/make» -f /home/nikita/Projects/build-calendarwidget-Desktop_Qt_5_14_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/Makefile qmake_all
make: Цель «qmake_all» не требует выполнения команд.
14:56:34: Процесс «/usr/bin/make» завершился успешно.
14:56:34: Запускается: «/usr/bin/make» -j4
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -Wextra -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../calendarwidget -I. -I/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -isystem /usr/include/libdrm -I/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o ../calendarwidget/main.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -Wextra -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../calendarwidget -I. -I/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -isystem /usr/include/libdrm -I/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o window.o ../calendarwidget/window.cpp
g++ -pipe -g -Wall -Wextra -dM -E -o moc_predefs.h /opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/mkspecs/features/data/dummy.cpp
/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/bin/moc -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB --include /home/nikita/Projects/build-calendarwidget-Desktop_Qt_5_14_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/moc_predefs.h -I/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I/home/nikita/Projects/calendarwidget -I/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I/usr/include/c++/7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7 -I/usr/include/c++/7/backward -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include ../calendarwidget/window.h -o moc_window.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -Wextra -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../calendarwidget -I. -I/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -isystem /usr/include/libdrm -I/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o moc_window.o moc_window.cpp
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/lib -o calendarwidget main.o window.o moc_window.o   /opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so /opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so /opt/Qt/5.14.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so -lGL -lpthread   
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
Makefile:281: recipe for target 'calendarwidget' failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [calendarwidget] Error 1
14:56:37: Процесс «/usr/bin/make» завершился с кодом 2.
Ошибка при сборке/развёртывании проекта calendarwidget (комплект: Desktop Qt 5.14.1 GCC 64bit)
Во время выполнения этапа «Сборка»
14:56:37: Прошло времени: 00:03.
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/584058/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-cannot-find-lgl?rq=1
Попробуйте так.

Comment: InTar, спасибо работает, видать пропустил, когда искал